# Create horizontal lines in multi line edittext

Tags: android

I want to create horizontal lines in the edittext. I looked online and found this class. How do I call this class in my activity where edittext et1 is?
Thanks

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

// we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(R.color.edit_note_line); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //int count = getLineCount();

    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();

    int count = height / line_height;

    if (getLineCount() > count)
        count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your `EditText` with the custom view from that class, being `LinedEditText`. You are not modifying an existing `EditText` you are replacing it with a new instance of a class that extends the `EditText` class.

If you have an `EditText` defined in an xml file, you'd first need to replace it with a the new one. To do this, change it to use `<com.example.customviews.LinedEditText` replacing the first part with your package name.

In the Java part, simply change the instance to `LinedEditText` and the cast too ie `(LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1)`

Comment: i.e if my edittext is et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1); how would i call lined edittext here? Thanks

Comment: I changed my xml file as well as java and changed edittext code as you said. However the activity is crashing, any ideas?

Comment: It's giving error on this line, (LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

Comment: Then you're probably casting it to LinedEditText while the xml is still an EditText

Comment: works now, it needed to be done like this  <view
        class="com.appname.LinedEditText"